# Python Method variable

Tags: python, class, variables, methods, attributes

I'm learning Python and have got myself in a bit of a muddle with variables in class methods.
With the following code - what have I created with "file_list"? Am I right in assuming this is just class internal variable, not a class attribute?

```
class Storage:

    def __init__(self, folder_path):
        self._path=folder_path
        file_list = glob.glob(self._path + '/*.txt')
```

(I need "file_list" to iterate through files to create a dictionary)

Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: It's a local variable in the `__init__` method. It will become inaccessible after init is done

Comment: It is a *local variable* to your *instance* method `__init__` (note, it is not a class method)

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for the fast reply :-)